# Error 404 File not found when installing tensorflow Windows 7

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, installation, anaconda

Trying to execute code given on tensorflow web page:
C:> pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

Several errors result - all of this nature:
HTTP Error 404 while getting  https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
HTTP error - Not Found

Are these files to be found elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the link is working as I just tried and had no issue. Can i recommend that you look at using the latest version of Tensorflow instead of 0.12 if you are starting fresh? This may save you hassle in the future!

Thanks

Comment: just tried typing: pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

Comment: If you are on windows can you check that your Python version is 3.5 and then try doing `pip uninstall tensorflow`.
Then try `pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow`